# Next.js: app directory responses always return a 500 response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm making an endpoint in next.js. All my bindings to postgres complete successfully, errors are caught and so on. When i make requests using the fetch API in another tab or postman the NextResponses are not sent and a HTTP 500 is always recieved without the body of the request that i've sent.

If this is relevant, this is in the callback of an asynchronous bcrypt hash.

```js
        const query: QueryConfig = {
            text: "INSERT INTO user_accounts(username, hash) VALUES($1, $2)",
            values: [username, hashedPassword]
        }
        try {
            await pool.query(query);
            return NextResponse.json({ success: true });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err, "\n\nERROR CAUGHT");
            return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
        }
```